# JQuery UI Styles For Main Web SIte

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am planning on incorporating JQuery UI into my application; has anyone had success in reusing the JQuery UI stylesheet for their own custom styles?  What I mean is, JQuery UI looks good with rounded corners and gradients, etc.  What I would like to do say use the gradient header of an accordion to the header for some of my panels that I don't use JQuery for 
(because it's static HTML).  Essentially, I don't want to have to create my own custom stylesheet.

Has anybody tried to reuse existing styles for their site and do you have any guidance?

Thanks.

Comment: i think the package come with its own css, you can check the css file

Comment: If you just copy the css of the style you want and apply it to what ever you want it will work fine.

Comment: I know it comes with CSS; I've been using JQuery UI with the CSS in my site.  But there are a variety of CSS classes to use, so I was wondering if someone built some examples of using the existing styles....  Essentially, I don't want to have to create my own custom stylesheet, but use those styles to style other features of my web application...

Comment: @Steven Why would he need to copy the css? Just use the same class.

Comment: This is a very good question. I am surprised that it is not given the attention it deserves here or on the JQueryIU site. The accepted answer is a good start but surely there has got to be a better way!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite easy. suppose you have a jqueryui css file named jquery.ui.theme.css and you would like to use header background image

```
<div style="height: 100px;" class="content-head ui-widget-header">
    <h1>This is a header</h1>
</div>
```

For more details about jqueryui css class http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API

Answer (score 0):

I would just set the class to match that of the jquery panel or header that I am using, then on my own style sheet, or in the jQuery style sheet, just add extra classes to override the bits that I need.

So if jQuery CSS was:

```
.content-header{
    background: url("/../..");
    width: 100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

I would just insert underneath (adding !important so that this style definitely overrides the previous one):

```
.my-content-header{
    width: 200px !important
}
```

Then have the html as:

```
<div id="header" class="content-header my-content-header">
```

Comment: If you're adding your own CSS after the jqueryui css, you won't need `!important`. It's bad practice to use `!important`, as you can always drilldown specificity without it.

Comment: Yeah I did wonder whether to include it, but sometimes when Im using included style sheets they just wont cascade correctly